# Converting Dataframe into dictionary using python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

[image: dataframe]

and i want to convert it into a dictionary using exactly this format:

[image: dictionary]

Do you guys have an idea on how to do that?

I also tried using `df.T.to_dict()` but it gives me some problems with the indices as well as a starting and end clip.

I figured it is some nesting problem, but I don't know how get rid of it :/

Please don't mind the harsh comments :) It is for a hate speech detection project!

Also I'm a new user so I don't have the reputation to post snippets directly! Sry for that!

Comment: Can you please provide more accurate example? `DataFrame` and `Dictionary` data does not match. I mean: this `dataframe` with this values I want to transform to  `dict` with this structure. According to this data solution can be: `result = comments_df["comments"].to_dict(orient="records")`. But without further more info i cannot help.

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). (Links formatted as code don't count as links, which is probably what was stopping you before.)

Comment: I assume you're using Pandas, so I added the [tag:pandas] tag for you. If that's incorrect, you can [edit] to fix it. Pandas has a bunch of idioms that aren't part of standard Python, so it's important to tag it.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this:

```
[{"comments":comments} for comments in dataframe.comments]
```

you can also use `.apply` which is multiple (even thousands) times faster than iterate item by item in the dataframe:

```
df.apply(lambda row: {"comments":row.comments}, axis=1).tolist()
```